# Use where condition in join/order mysql

Tags: mysql, pdo

I really don't know how to use "Where" condition in this sql query
I should use something like this :

> where rules_id != 6 
>   * rules_id = 6 => banned users rules

```html
 $stmt = $db_con->prepare("
 select * from users
 JOIN rules
 On users.rules_id = rules.rules_id
 order by rand() limit 1
");
```

thanks and sorry for my poor english.

Comment: you can simply get the answer by google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put it before the `order by`

```
$stmt = $db_con->prepare("select * from users
                            JOIN rules On users.rules_id = rules.rules_id
                        where users.rules_id != 6 
                        order by rand() 
                        limit 1");
```